# how to pass a variable from vb to javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have server-side VB code to retrieve an `access_token` and save it in the session. I want to make the token available client-side so I can use it to send an ajax request.

I tried to set the token in a hidden field. This works. The token shows in the field when I check via the browser dev tools.

I then tried to get the hidden field value in javascript with `getHiddenValue()`. This does not work. `getHiddenVaue()` does not execute. But when `funciones.RedirigiraUsuario()` is commented out, `getHiddenValues()` works.

`RedirigiraUsuario()` has a switch case to redirect a view depending on the profile

The vb code to set the token looks like this:

```
Dim url As String = funciones.getPropiedad(Me.Page, "urlWebApi") & 
"recuperarToken"
Dim data As New NameValueCollection()
data.Set("grant_type", "password")
data.Set("username", funciones.reemplaza_caracteres(txt_login.Text))

If ViewState("ESADMIN") Then
    data.Set("password", NegUsuario.get_GEN_claveUsuarios())
Else
    data.Set("password", contraseña)
End If

data.Set("clientid", "2")
'data.Set("idperfil", "63")
Dim sJson As String = funciones.ObtenerJsonWebApi(url, data)

If Not sJson = Nothing Then
    Dim json As Dictionary(Of String, String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(sJson)
    Session("TOKEN") = "Bearer " + json("access_token")
    'setting the token in hidden field
    inputToken.Value = "Bearer " + json("access_token")
    'here is the problem, this does not works, maybe the postback is the guilty
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ShowStatus", "javascript: getHiddenValue();", True)
End If

funciones.RedirigiraUsuario(Me)
```

Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div_login').hide();
        $('#div_login').fadeIn(1500);
        document.getElementById('div_login').scrollIntoView();
    });

    function incorrecto() {
        $("#div_login").addClass('go');
    }

    function getHiddenValue() {
        console.error("asdasdasdasda")
        let hdnField = document.getElementById('<%= inputToken.ClientID %>').value;
        showNotificacion("asdas",'info', 'center', 'top',200)
        localStorage.setItem("PabToken", hdnField)
        sessionStorage.setItem("PabToken", hdnField)
        return true
    }

</script>
```

How can I execute the `getHiddenValue()` function before postback, or get the token saved in the server-side?

### Edit

```
Public Shared Sub RedirigiraUsuario(ByRef pagina As Page)
    Select Case pagina.Session("PERFIL")
        Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "N"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
        Case "6"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/FormMantenedor/MAN_JefeEspecialidad.aspx")
        Case "7"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/BUS_General.aspx")
        Case "8"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/FormPabellon/GST_Detalle_Post_Anestesia.aspx")
        Case "9"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/FormTabla/ING_Tabla.aspx")
        Case "10", "11", "12", "15"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/FormPreTabla/GST_Pre_Tabla.aspx")
        Case "14"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/GST_Camas.aspx")
        Case "13"
            pagina.Response.Redirect("~/FormPabellon/REP_Pabellon.aspx")
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: If the client ID is being troublesome, then you can add the attribute `ClientIDMode = "static"` to the `inputToken` control, then it will use the ID without changing it, so you could use `let hdnField = document.getElementById('yourChosenID').value;` instead. [Control.ClientIDMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. I need to repeat this: I'm not sure.

But my best guess is the problem is this line:

```
document.getElementById('<%= inputToken.ClientID %>')
```

What I think is happening is if `funciones.RedirigiraUsuario(Me)` results in a redirect, the `<%= inputToken.ClientID %>` expression will not resolve correctly.

To fix this, you need to set the clientID somewhere the javascript will be able to retrieve it *before* doing anything might cause a redirect.

The other potential issue is the reliance on `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`. It's possible a redirect will have the effect of resetting the script manager.

I think it's likely **both** issues are in play.

At very least you should be able to use the browser dev tools to find the function: does it have the correct clientID? Is it there at all?

Unfortunately, it's been far too long since I used Web Forms regularly. My recollection of how that all fits together is no longer clear, so this is as much help as I can give.

Comment: thanksl for answer, i will add the `funciones.RedirigiraUsuario(Me)`

Comment: when  `funciones.RedirigiraUsuario(Me)` is commented, it works. Redirecting is the problem. i tried use a "delay" 3 seconds but it does not work

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ShowStatus", "javascript: getHiddenValue();", True)` is ignored when i use a redirect. btw thanks for your answer

Comment: Remember: while your VB code is still running, the page in the browser _doesn't exist_, and it will not exist until the VB code for the entire page lifecycle is completely finished. If you redirect to a new page, all the work building up the previous page is **thrown away**.

Comment: thanks, i solved. i dont know if it is the best way to solve but it works. in the page load function on master page, i checked if the session has a "token", if token exist save the token in the local storage with javascript.

Comment: al least it works while i find a better ways to do it